# Download Facebook Page Private Messages

Tags: facebook-graph-api, message

I am using GraphAPI to download posts from a Facebook Page that I am admin on.
https://graph.facebook.com/facebookpageID/posts

I would also like to download Private Messages and TimeLine Posts? How to do that?

Thanks!

Regards,
Cyril

Comment: if your goal is to avoid facebook authentication, use facebook rss feed to get timeline posts

Comment: No. My software uses the access token of my clients to get the posts and messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the `conversations` endpoint `http://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/conversations` with `read_page_mailboxes` permission https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Comment: This is what I get for a page I created or another page that I am admin on:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#298) You must be a developer of the application", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 298
  }
}

Comment: @CyrilJoudieh could you update the question with the actual code you are using

Comment: $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$facebookpageID.'/conversations'
$json = file_get_contents($url);