# How to download all Facebook Page Messages?

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping

I want to download all chat messages in the Facebook Account that I manage to help building a chatbot.

I've checked other posts, such as [Download Facebook Page Private Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914723/download-facebook-page-private-messages) and [How to download all Facebook 'posts to page' (without scrolling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965813/how-to-download-all-facebook-posts-to-page-without-scrolling), but none of them allow to download ALL messages from the page.

Facebook requests using the API only returns the results partially, therefore I need to move from page to page to find all messages. While I can loop through some messages using **facebook-api**, there's this concept of paginating that I cannot find documentation about.

So far, I've got this piece of code:

```py
import facebook
import multiprocessing as mp
import requests

app_id = "XXXXX"
token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token, version = 3.1)
message_dict = {}


#Function to help with the multiprocessing
def get_conversation_from_id(conversation_id):
    conversation = dict()
    conversation[conversation_id] = []
    messages = graph.request(conversation_id + "?fields=messages{" + conversation_id + "}")
    for message_data in messages['messages']['data']:
        try:
            message = graph.request(message_data['id'] + "?fields=message")
            conversation[conversation_id].append(message['message'])
        except facebook.GraphAPIError:
            continue
    conversation[conversation_id] = conversation[conversation_id][::-1]
    return conversation

conversations = graph.request(app_id + "?fields=conversations{0}&amp")

#A while loop that is to be broken once no more "next" pages are found
while True:
    try:
        pool = mp.Pool(10)
        results = pool.map(get_conversation_from_id, [conv_id['id'] for conv_id in conversations['conversations']['data']])
        print(results)
        pool.close()
        conversations = graph.request(app_id + "?fields=conversations{" + str(i) + "}&amp;limit=100")
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        continue
```

I expect to be able to **paginate over all pages** (I can't even find information in the requests to attempt to paginate to another answer subset), from which I'll save the messages to Json for further processing.

Comment: I know this question is about Python but incase you didn't know, you can download all your messages manually from Facebook here: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=your_facebook_information

Comment: Not for webpages...